# How to handle end signal in a node.js Writable stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

Using the `stream.Writable` base class of node.js 0.10, how can I handle the case of a consumer calling `.end()` and thus signaling no more data will be available?

In [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback_1) the only method told to be implemented in `Writable` subclasses is `_write`, but I can't find any clean way to notice when the input has been exhausted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly, as of 0.10, node's `stream.Writable` does not support this in a standard, clean way. This issue is already being discussed here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7348

In that page several workarounds are proposed. TomFrost's [flushwritable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/flushwritable) module looks like an acceptable solution for the time being.

That module provides a `FlushWritable` class which is used exactly like `stream.Writable` but supporting a new `_flush` method which is invoked after the consumer calls `.end()` but before the `finish` event is emitted.

Answer (score 3):

The answer I found was to listen to the [`finish`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event.

> When the `end()` method has been called, and all data has been flushed to the underlying system, this event is emitted.

I haven't tested it yet, but the way I'm reading this, all calls to `_write` must be completed before the `finish` event is emitted.

Comment: Has the Writable Stream API has changed because now the docs recommends to implement  `_write()`, `_writev()`, and `_final()`?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I ran into this in 2020. If others find their way here: this is now implemented in `Writable._final()` as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_final_callback)

Comment: I cannot edit it: there -> their.

Answer (score 0):

from the [source code](https://github1s.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/writable.js#L595) of nodejs writable streams.
calling `end` will fire `finish` event if the streams is able to be ended.
If you the streams doesn't have a `_final` function, it will be a `prefinish` event fired also.

Answer (score -1):

Considering what you asked

> > how can I handle the case of a consumer calling .end() and thus signaling no more data will be available?

, you should check when your input (a readable stream) has ended, not your output (your writable stream). So, in this case, you can check for the `end` event on your readable stream, like:

```
readableStream.on('end', function () {
  // do what you want with your writable stream, maybe call the end() method
  writableStream.end();
});
```

You can even pipe the readable stream to the writable stream, if you don't want to manage the flow yourself:

```
readableStream.pipe(writableStream);
```

Comment: I'm implementing a writeable stream. Other stream is writing data into mine, either with `.pipe()` or directly with `.write()`. At some point in time the input will be completely flushed and my stream will receive a `.end()` call (either directly, or as part of `.pipe()` behavior). I want my writable stream to detect that and e.g. close the file it was writing to.

Comment: Ok, understood. So, in this case, an option would be to implement a method in your writable stream which receives the input stream as an argument and checks if it has ended, and then close the file.